# How to put a timeout on Transform

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

The `XslCompiledTransform.Transform` will hang under certain conditions (stack overflow, infinite loop, etc). This is a data (input) dependent error, so I don't have complete control in preventing it. If this happens, I'd like to be notified gracefully, but I don't want it to destroy my application process and hence the GUI where the user is inputting the input, which may be "valid" but "incomplete".

If I run the xslt file manually, I get

> Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException

But `XslCompiledTransform.Transform()` will hang my application **forever**.

So, I want to wrap that call in a timeout, but nothing I've tried seems to work. It still hangs the application.

I want the thread that has the try block to not be hung. I want to create two tasks, one for Transform and the other timeout. Then start both at the same time. I don't know but I think the `Run` is running before the outer statement gets a chance to wire up the timeout and use the `WhenAny`.

How can this be fixed?

**Update**

I updated the code to reflect my current attempt. I can get into the `if` block if it times out, but whether I abort the thread or not, the application still hangs. I don't understand what it is about `XslCompiledTransform.Transform` that insists on taking the whole application down if it goes down.

```
public static Object Load(string mathML)
{
  if (mathML == Notebooks.InputCell.EMPTY_MATH)
    return null;
  XmlDocument input = new XmlDocument();
  input.LoadXml(mathML);
  XmlDocument target = new XmlDocument(input.CreateNavigator().NameTable);
  using (XmlWriter writer = target.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
  {
    try
    {
      Thread thread = null;
      var task = Task.Run(() => 
      {
        thread = Thread.CurrentThread;
        XmlTransform.Transform(input, writer);
      });
      if (!task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
      {
        thread.Abort();
        throw new TimeoutException();
      }
    }
    catch (XsltException xex)
    {
      if (xex.Message == "An item of type 'Attribute' cannot be constructed within a node of type 'Root'.")
        return null;
      else
        throw;
    }
  }
  return Load(target);
}
```

Comment: `.Result` is a blocking call. You'll need to make `Load` `async` and `await Task.WhenAny(..)`.

Comment: @JSteward, thank you, but I'm afraid that does not prevent the application from hanging when the transform goes into never never land

Comment: Farm it out to a separate process. `TerminateProcess` is very reliable. Overkill? Not really. The problem is that if a synchronous method decides to keep running, there's nothing you can do short of aborting the thread (which is such a bad mechanism that the general recommendation is to just exit the process instead). Tasks don't fix that -- they instead allow you to ignore the runaway thread and continue, which doesn't fix the underlying problem that you have a runaway thread, and will eventually result in an unresponsive *machine* if you repeat this trick.

Comment: Alternatively, look into other libraries for XSLT transform, like Saxon, that may take more pains to avoid these problems. Disclaimer: no personal experience.

Comment: The fact that the thread isn't responding to `Thread.Abort` is a sign that it's blocked in a `finally`, or in unmanaged code, since `Thread.Abort` only takes effect at a point the CLR decides that now might not be a terrible time to abort. If you want to get to the bottom of things, you can break out a debugger and check the stack at the point it's not doing anything, but this assumes you can cook up actual workarounds for the problems you find, whatever they are. My money's still on sequestering this stuff in its own service, or switching libraries.

Comment: A `Thread.Abort` request on a worker thread (like the one `Task` is running on) may or may not be completely ignored, but is certainly a terrible idea regardless. If you want to explicitly manipulate a thread, don't use `Task.Run` at all, just use `new Thread()` and `Thread.Join` to wait on it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I believe that's effectively what I did. Check out my answer. Except, I looked as the "compiled transform assembly" with reflector and it's no longer and xslt file, but rather generated code.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I do appreciate all the feedback. Now that I fixed the hang, I tried to get rid of the `Thread.Abort()`. Unfortunately, the application still hangs without it. Even though at least it didn't kill Visual Studio. `Thread.Abort()` didn't even work until I compiled the transform into the seperate assembly. I'll try `new Thread()` and `Thread.Join`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Here's how I solved the issue

I took my xsl and compiled it into an assembly and referenced that assembly from my project (which is called `Library`)

Advantages:

- Fixed the hang
- Compiled xslt into an assembly is supposedly much faster

Disadvantages:

- You tell me! I don't know :)

**Library Properties / Build Events / Pre-build Event**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7 Tools\xsltc.exe" /settings:script+ /class:Transform "myStylesheet.xslt"
```

**Library / References**

`+ myStylesheet.dll`

**Loading the compiled transform**

```
private static XslCompiledTransform xslTransform;
private static XslCompiledTransform XslTransform
{
  get
  {
    if (xslTransform == null)
    {
      xslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
      xslTransform.Load(typeof(Transform));
    }
    return xslTransform;
  }
}
```

**Calling the transform**

Same as updated code in the Question